# Remove 'Enable Remote Control' for a local User account

Tags: powershell

I've been looking at using powershell to set up a local account, we have a requirement where the `Enable Remote Control` option should be deselected.

This option is under `Users`, Right click and select `Properties` and under the `Remote` tab untick `Remote control`.

The only thing I can find online is how to enable or disable remote desktop using powershell :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using P/Invoke; example follows.

```
#requires -version 2

Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WTSQueryUserConfig(
  string pServerName,
  string pUserName,
  int WTSConfigClass,
  out IntPtr ppBuffer,
  out uint pBytesReturned);
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WTSSetUserConfig(
  string pServerName,
  string pUserName,
  int WTSConfigClass,
  IntPtr pBuffer,
  uint DataLength);
"@ -Namespace Win32Api -Name WtsApi32

$WTS_CONFIG_SHADOWING_SETTINGS = 14

function WTSQueryUserConfigShadowSettings {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [String] $computerName,
    [String] $userName
  )
  $pBuffer = [IntPtr]::Zero
  $bytesReturned = 0
  $success = [Win32Api.WtsApi32]::WTSQueryUserConfig(
    $computerName,                   # pServerName
    $userName,                       # pUserName
    $WTS_CONFIG_SHADOWING_SETTINGS,  # WTSConfigClass
    [Ref] $pBuffer,                  # ppBuffer
    [Ref] $bytesReturned             # pBytesReturned
  )
  if ( $success ) {
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReadInt32($pBuffer)
    [Win32Api.WtsApi32]::WTSFreeMemory($pBuffer)
  }
  else {
    $exception = New-Object ComponentModel.Win32Exception ([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error())
    Write-Error -Exception $exception
  }
}

function WTSSetUserConfigShadowSettings {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [String] $computerName,
    [String] $userName,
    [Int] [ValidateRange(0,4)] $shadowSettings
  )
  $pNewValue = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([Type] [Int]))
  [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::WriteInt32($pNewValue, $shadowSettings)
  $dataLength = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($pNewValue)
  $success = [Win32Api.WtsApi32]::WTSSetUserConfig(
    $computerName,                    # pServerName
    $userName,                        # pUserName
    $WTS_CONFIG_SHADOWING_SETTINGS,   # WTSConfigClass
    $pNewValue,                       # pBuffer
    $dataLength                       # DataLength
  )
  if ( $success ) {
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($pNewValue)
  }
  else {
    $exception = New-Object ComponentModel.Win32Exception ([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error())
    Write-Error -Exception $exception
  }
}

function Get-RDShadowingSetting {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
      [String[]] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $UserName,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
      [String[]] $ComputerName = [Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
  )
  process {
    foreach ( $computerNameItem in $ComputerName ) {
      foreach ( $userNameItem in $userName ) {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          "ComputerName"       = $computerNameItem
          "UserName"           = $userNameItem
          "RDShadowingSetting" = WTSQueryUserConfigShadowSettings $computerNameItem $userNameItem
        } | Select-Object ComputerName,UserName,RDShadowingSetting
      }
    }
  }
}

function Set-RDShadowingSetting {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
      [String[]] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $UserName,
    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
      [Int] [ValidateRange(0,4)] $RDShadowingSetting,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
      [String[]] $ComputerName = [Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
  )
  process {
    foreach ( $computerNameItem in $ComputerName ) {
      foreach ( $userNameItem in $userName ) {
        WTSSetUserConfigShadowSettings $computerNameItem $userNameItem $RDShadowingSetting
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `Get-RDShadowingSetting` function returns a value `0` through `4` in the `RDShadowingSetting` property that corresponds to the setting you want to use:

```
Value  Meaning
-----  -------
0      Disable remote control
1      Enabled/require user's permission/interact with the session
2      Enabled/don't require user's permission/interact with the session
3      Enabled/require user's permission/view the user's session
4      Enabled/don't require user's permission/view the user's session
```

The `Set-RDShadowingSetting` function lets you update the value for a user; e.g.:

```
Set-RDShadowingSetting "KenDyer" 0
```

This would disable remote control for the `KenDyer` account on the local computer.

The `WTSQueryUserConfigShadowSettings` and `WTSSetUserConfigShadowSettings` functions are the functions that execute the actual Windows API calls.

(Getting a list of computer or user names is left as an exercise to the reader.)

API documentation link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested: I wrote a PowerShell module for getting and setting all of the RD user settings. This may be useful if you need to manage these settings on machines where the settings aren't "surfaced" from a GUI or command-line tool. The module is called `RDUserSetting` and you can get it here:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PowerShell-RDUserSetting

Using this module, the command that would answer the question here would be:

```
Set-RDUserSetting kendyer -RDRemoteControlSetting Disabled
```

You can also view RD user settings using `Get-RDUserSetting` and the pipeline. Example:

```
Get-RDUserSetting |
  Where-Object { $_.RDRemoteControlSetting -ne "Disabled" } |
  Set-RDUserSetting -RDRemoteControlSetting Disabled
```

This command would set the `RDRemoteControlSetting` property to `Disabled` for every user on the local computer where it's not already set. (Warning: Don't do this on a domain controller.)